# Oracle advanced union

Tags: sql, oracle, union

Is there any advanced Oracle SQL methods to solve this kind of situation?

Simplified:
Two queries returns **primary_key_value** and **other_value**.
Both queries always return primary_key_value but other_value might be null.

So how I can union those two queries so that it returns always those rows which has other_value, but if both queries are having other_value = null with same primary key, then only one row should be returned.

I know this is so stupid case. But specifications were like this :)

Example:
First query:

```
A  |  B
=======
1  | X
2  | 
3  | 
4  | Z
```

Second query:

```
A  |  B
=======
1  | Y
2  | 
3  | Z
4  |
```

So result need to be like this:

```
A  |  B
=======
1  | X
1  | Y
2  | 
3  | Z
4  | Z
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use analytics:

```
SQL> WITH q1 AS (
  2     SELECT 1 a, 'X' b FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3     SELECT 2 a, ''  b FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4     SELECT 3 a, ''  b FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5     SELECT 4 a, 'Z' b FROM DUAL
  6  ), q2 AS (
  7     SELECT 1 a, 'Y' b FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  8     SELECT 2 a, ''  b FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  9     SELECT 3 a, 'Z' b FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 10     SELECT 4 a, ''  b FROM DUAL
 11  )
 12  SELECT a, b
 13    FROM (SELECT a, b,
 14                 rank() over(PARTITION BY a 
 15                             ORDER BY decode(b, NULL, 2, 1)) rnk
 16             FROM (SELECT * FROM q1
 17                    UNION
 18                   SELECT * FROM q2))
 19   WHERE rnk = 1;

         A B
---------- -
         1 X
         1 Y
         2 
         3 Z
         4 Z
```

Comment: There is only one problem: I cannot use where-clause in q1 and q2. I have to put that to top level, and then we have a performance problem. It's doing full table scan in q1 and q2 queries... Or at least by default it's doing without any optimizer hints.

Comment: Why can't you put a where clause in Q1 and Q2?

Comment: This SQL is in view, so when I'm using that view the where clause is then put to top level depending of chosen ID's (UI). That could be maybe solved with building view dynamically and adding where clauses to middle of the view...

Comment: Ah ok, the problem is that I'm not sure the optimizer is smart enough to figure that `(Q1 UNION Q2) WHERE x=y` is equivalent to `(Q1 WHERE x=y) UNION (Q2 WHERE x=y)`. I recall seeing the optimizer making this transformation with a UNION ALL. You might want to try a UNION ALL and use SELECT DISTINCT when you select from the view.

Comment: Still it's doing a full table scan.

Comment: But if I just remove the analytics part and place where clause in top level then it's using indexes :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want use something really advanced, use model clause http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2007/10/sql-model-clause-tutorial-part-one.html
But, in real life, using such things usually means bad-designed data model

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at is that you want all possible values from the union of column A then left outer outer join these with the non-null values from column B, thus only showing null in B when there is no non-null value to display.
roughly:

```
WITH q1 as (whatever),
     q2 as (whatever)
SELECT All_A.A, BVals.B
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT A FROM (SELECT A FROM q1 UNION SELECT A FROM q2)) All_A,
     (SELECT A,B FROM q1 WHERE B IS NOT NULL
      UNION
      SELECT A,B FROM q2 WHERE B IS NOT NULL) BVals
WHERE All_A.A = BVals.A (+)
```

Also pruning the unwanted nulls explicitly could do the same job:

```
WITH q3 AS (q1_SELECT UNION q2_SELECT)
SELECT A,B
FROM q3 main
WHERE NOT ( B IS NULL AND
            EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM q3 x WHERE main.A = x.A and x.B IS NOT NULL) )
```